# How can we implement a modular framework with set behaviors?

Tags: python

*This post has been edited to reflect suggestions relating to question clarity and intent

*I have conceptualized a solution to this problem, and I am currently developing the code. I will update this post when the solution is complete. This comment will be removed when I post my solution.

My goal is to implement a modular framework that meets the following requirements:

1. There is a single instance that manages all of the modular components; I will refer to it as the `Engine`, and the modular components as `Model`s. The `Engine` must provide the following services:

   - Direct information to each `Model`s subscribed functions; I will refer to these as `callback`s.
   - Run functions belonging to an instance of a `Model`, if the model has requested that the function be run; I will refer to these as `update`s.
2. A `Model` can be defined and instantiated without an `Engine`. The `Model` has no dependencies on the `Engine` (although without an `Engine`, the model is mostly useless).
3. There should be some attribute applied to each `callback` and `update` in a `Model` so that, when added to the `Engine`, the `Engine` can determine the purpose of each function in the `Model`.
4. Each `update` is defined with update criteria, consisting of Boolean logic and a priority. An `update` will only run successfully if the update criteria are `True`. If the update criteria are `False`, the `update` will raise an `Exception`
5. `update`s are called by the `Engine`, highest priority first.
6. Information can only be passed to an `Engine` by `return`ing a value in a `update`. Information passed to the `Engine` is distributed immediately to `callback`s.
7. Each `callback` is defined with a topic. The callback will only be called by the `Engine`, if the information topic matches the `callback` topic.

It is my current understanding that decorators would be effective in implementing the desired behavior. I think we could do the following:

1. Create a decorator named `callback`, that takes a parameter `tag` which is set as an attribute on the decorated function. `tag` denotes the type of information that the function should receive.
2. Create a decorator named 'update', that takes parameters `logic` and `priority` which are set as attributes on the decorated function. `logic` is a callable that returns a Boolean. `priority` denotes the priority of the function.

Using decorators would allow me to define Models without `Engine` dependency. The `Engine` can utilize `inspect` to get functions in each `Model` that have the relevant attributes.

After implementing various attempts, I have the following concerns:

1. Decorators are applied at instantiation, and as a result cannot accept `self` as an argument.

Comment: I don't think we have all the necessary logic bits to understand this problem, especially code wise, also your paragraphs are very dense, please try to split/simplify them.

Comment: What do you think needs more clarification?

Comment: @Deemo You can start by creating a [mcve] that we can run ourselves.

Comment: Please see my updated post.

Comment: @Deemo, it is an interesting project, but it’s also way out of SO’s scope.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still unclear about the source of the arguments, why you are attaching flags to functions and where this exception should be used...

This seems more like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) than anything else.

Nonetheless, decorators are cool so I wrote this which might point you in the right direction.

```py
import typing as T
from datetime import date

def testmonday() -> bool:
    return date.today().weekday() == 0  # when I wrote this it was Monday

def testfalse() -> bool:
    return False

def runonany(*tests: T.Callable[[], bool]):
    def wrapper(func):
        if any(t() for t in tests):
            return func
        else:
            return lambda: None
    return wrapper

@runonany(testmonday, testfalse, lambda: False)
def runfunc():
    return "running"

@runonany(testfalse, lambda: True)
def dontrunfunc():
    return "how did you get this ?"

# Or if flags are a group of booleans

FLAGS = [True, False, True, False]

def runonanyflag():
    def wrapper(func):
        if any(FLAGS):
            return func
        else:
            return lambda: None

    return wrapper

@runonanyflag
def runfuncflag():
    return "also running"

print(runfunc())
print(dontrunfunc())  # None
print(runfuncflag())
```

Comment: I think your solution is very close to what I am trying to achieve, but there are a few issues that I noticed. It seems like your solution only checks the flags when function is created; I need the flags to be checked every time that the function is called.

Comment: Decorators are applied to functions, so, when the function is created. I'm pretty sure you can capture the underlying function's arguments in a decorator, so that might be the way to go for you, but the function is affected upon creation. You can decorate with class objects also which allow for stateful decorators similar to functools lru_cache.

Comment: Please see my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your `Model` is nothing but a set of some `Callback`s, somehow tagged, with the only intention to be called by the `Engine`.

In that case it is enough to have simple abstract class defining all known accepted callbacks by their rightful names. It’s easy to know if a given callback is implemented: one deadly stupid option is to catch the `NotImplemented` on the `Engine` side.

Further more: your `Engine` could expose a way to register expected `Callback` upfront, in which case design is approaching the standard proven by Time, waterproof and bulletproof Observer pattern.

I would suggest to take a really careful look into so called “reactive extensions”, especially in JavaScript (`rxjs`), and it’s core interfaces: `Observer` and `Observable`.

Comment: I agree with your suggestions, but some are not valid in this case. It is a specific requirement that a `Model` not be passed anything from the `Engine`; the `Model` is independent of the `Engine`. Additionally there is no standard list of callbacks that may be implemented. The only standardization between `Model`s is that they can use a decorator to denote which functions are to be used for recieving/sending information; `Models` may be anything from a database to a GUI.

Comment: Observer patter does not require your Engine to pass something to a Callback, anyway. It also fine with dynamic tagging — when there is no a priori known list of named callbacks.

Comment: I am looking into `rjxs`; it is an interesting approach. I think it may not work for me, as I think it would ignore priority. My current concept is to use events that are assigned a priority. I must respect priority, as I do not want to do some calculations if others are not checked first. Also, I think observer might require you to pass something to the object constructor; I want to avoid this.

Comment: @Deemo it will respect priority if you build your pipeline correctly.  Prioritizing does not change the concept. I strongly suggest you first learn how it works and later decide if you even need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: RxPy looks promising. Thanks for the suggestions